# How to handle different route value types between Actionlink and Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Controller Action accepts int id. What to do when calling from View ActionLink with string id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC binding infrastructure will convert the string to an int before invoking your controller action method (and throw an exception if conversion fails).